# Will ThePhotoStick Omni work with Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, compatibility, usb-drive, preinstallation

Will ThePhotoStick Omni work with Ubuntu 20.04? I have several platforms with pictures scattered all over the place. ThePhotoStick Omni claims it is compatible with Windows, Mac, iOS, and Android, and it comes preinstalled with software for finding, backing up and restoring photos on these platforms.

This product makes superwhamodyne statements, but does not come right out and say "Yep, we got you covered on Ubuntu". Does anyone have any direct experience with ThePhotoStick Omni?

Comment: **It's basically a SCAM**. And no, fortunately it won't work in any Linux distro, at least not differently than any other mass storage device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't think that it is a duplicate of that question because a storage device that has preinstalled software for Windows/macOS/Android that doesn't say on the manufacturer's website that it is compatible with Linux usually works fine as a storage device, but its preinstalled software does not work on Linux.

Comment: I agree. But anyway we can't tell for sure if it works and how.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't think Dano wants to install Ubuntu on his mass storage device. I think he wants to know if his mass storage device is fully compatible with Ubuntu including any software that's preinstalled on that storage device.

Comment: @karel Yes, that was and is my understanding as well. The "it won't work" part refers to the software inside. I though my comment was clear enough: It's an overpriced USB stick with software of dubious origin and doesn't run in Linux.

Comment: @ChanganAuto There are several similar USB flash drive photo backup and restore devices on Amazon. Some of them have more storage capacity than ThePhotoStick Omni and some are cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

My personal experience is that a storage device that has preinstalled software for Windows/Mac/Android that doesn't say on the manufacturer's website that it is compatible with Linux usually works fine as a storage device, but its preinstalled software does not work on Linux. Some manufacturers have a chat feature on their websites where you can ask if a device's software is compatible with Linux. There are several models of USB storage devices that are similar to ThePhotoStick Omni. You're ahead of the game if you can find a model that the chatbot/expert says is compatible with Linux. Of course it will work on Linux. Every USB storage device works on Linux. What you really want to know is if the storage device's preinstalled software works on Linux.